# Should pallets that lock currency check for MaxLocks?

Tags: lockable-currency

In the trait config for `LockableCurrency` there's a type `MaxLocks`. I am writing a pallet that uses `set_lock` and `remove_lock` from this trait. Should I implement checks to see if I am not exceeding `MaxLocks` before calling `set_lock`? If yes, how should I check how many locks an account already has?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current solution is to require the runtime-author to set `MaxLocks` to the number of unique `LockIdentifier` values in the runtime. This alleviates any need to check the number of locks since there can only ever be as many locks as identifiers as each identifier can result in at most one lock per account.

If `MaxLocks` is underestimated then it's likely not the end of the world; it means that the weights and PoV footprint estimations will be a little lower than they should be, but there's enough headroom in both of these that a small error shouldn't cause anything catastrophic to happen.

(This does place some effort on the part of the runtime-author and a mistake might be made. This will likely be abstracted away in the future by requiring the `LockIdentifier` type to be an amalgamation type similar to `Origin`, `Event` and `Error` but whose values are enumerable.)

Comment: To add to this, the technical reason why "it's likely not the end of the world" is that `MaxLocks` are used with `WeakBoundedVec`: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/65b44e91bedd6961ef30cef08e89273b7d98b4ed/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L541